# Can Graphcmd tool of Visual Studio generate dgml file from dll files

Tags: graph, dgml

I want to create dgml file (dependence graph) from list of dll files OR solution, project. Can I do that with Graphcmd by command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use GraphCmd to create DGML files only for DLLs or other DGML files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx#GenerateDGMLCommand).

Comment: Can you pretty pretty please provide an example command line call to GraphCmd for a DLL input file? I'm having a terrible time trying to get it to work - I keep getting "Data at the root level is invalid". My cmd: GraphCmd.exe -all -exceptions -input my.dll -output my.dgml